# Cannot open Tor without it closing immediately

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, brave

I've been trying for hours to use Tor, but it always closes briefly after opening. I've checked through task manager and it seems to actually launch for a moment. I've already set it to run as Administrator. The Windows version in cmd gave me a blank line, so I've installed the Linux instead and used the --verbose option, and it tells me "Cannot load XPCOM" (output shown below). I've found online that Webroot's the culprit, but I don't *have* Webroot, nor have I downloaded any antivirus software. I've even tried turning off some Windows Defender features, but I didn't notice any difference.

```
$ ./start-tor-browser.desktop --verbose

Launching './Browser/start-tor-browser --detach --verbose'...
XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /mnt/c/Users/username/Desktop/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/libxul.so:
libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Couldn't load XPCOM.
```

Update: I've tried using Brave instead. It worked for about 5 seconds, then stopped. Now, each time I launch it, I get the same exact issue as with Tor. I've tried turning Windows Defender off and running it as Administrator just like before, nothing changed.

Edit: I should probably mention that firefox doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have a library missing. I guess these commands will help you out with the problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libdbus-glib-1-2
```

After installing libdbus-glib-1-2 try restarting your tor browser.